# How can I animate transitions for different views with distinct animations by toggling a single isShown property in SwiftUI?

Tags: swiftui

I want to have each RoundedRectangle's transition animated with a different animation and using only the showView property to trigger all transitions.

Here is my code:

```swift
struct StackoverflowRep: View {
    
    @State var showView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            VStack {
                if showView {
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                        .overlay(Text(".transition(.slide)").foregroundColor(.blue))
                        .animation(.easeIn) // this works like I'd want it to
                        .transition(.slide)
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                        .overlay(Text(".transition(.move())").foregroundColor(.blue))
                        .animation(.spring(), value: showView)
                        .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
                    RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                        .overlay(Text("no transition: just opacity").foregroundColor(.blue))
                        .animation(.easeInOut, value: self.showView) // This does nothing

                        .opacity(showView ? 1.0 : 0.0)
                }
            }
            .padding()
            Button("Toggle") {

// I don't want to use withAnimation {}. I know it works. But I'd like to use just one showView value.
                showView.toggle()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct StackoverflowRep_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        StackoverflowRep()
    }
}
```

I used to accomplish this by using just `.animation(.spring())` without the latest init adding a value. But it has been deprecated.

Is there something I'm missing without getting to hacky? Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can apply the `.animation(_, value:` to a `Group` that encloses the conditional view.

I did the following test that generates some strange results:

- direct toggle works on `.transition(.slide)` and `.transition(.move)` but not on `.scale` nor `.opacity`
- animated toggle works on all, but ignores indivdual animations on `.scale` and `.opcacity`.

[image]

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var showView = false
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
                Group {
                    if showView {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                            .overlay(Text(".transition(.slide)").foregroundColor(.blue))
                            .transition(.slide)
                    }
                }
                .animation(.easeOut(duration: 1), value: showView)
                
                Group {
                    if showView {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                            .overlay(Text(".transition(.move())").foregroundColor(.blue))
                            .transition(.move(edge: .trailing))
                    }
                }
                .animation(.spring(), value: showView)

                Group {
                    if showView {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                            .overlay(Text(".transition(.scale)").foregroundColor(.blue))
                            .transition(.scale)
                    }
                }
                .animation(.easeOut(duration: 2), value: showView)

                Group {
                    if showView {
                        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 30)
                            .overlay(Text("no transition: just opacity").foregroundColor(.blue))
                            .transition(.opacity)
                    }
                }
                .animation(.easeOut(duration: 4), value: showView)

            
            Button("Toggle") {
                    showView.toggle()
            }

            Button("Toggle with animation") {
                withAnimation {
                    showView.toggle()
                }
            }
        }
        .padding()
   }
}
```